# Creating and pushing back a vector of functions

Tags: c++

I would like to create a vector of functions and "push_back" it, but don't know how it is done correctly. Thx, in advance. That's what I have so far:

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    int function1()
    {
        return (a+b)*c;
    }

    typedef std::function<int> function1;
    typedef std::vector<function> functionsvector;


    functionvector.push_back(function1);
```

Comment: First, learn [what `typedef` means](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/). You're not using it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `typedef` here. That means you are aliasing those types to the names you specify, not creating instances of them.

You should do this instead:

```
//create a vector of functions which take no arguments and return an int
std::vector<std::function<int()>> functionvector {};
//implicitly converts the function pointer to a std::function<int()> and pushes
functionvector.push_back(function1);
```

Comment: `code` std::vector<std::function<int()>> functionvector {};                                          `code`             It shows me an error before the first cury bracked: "A semicolon was expected".

Comment: Did you `#include <functional>` ?

Comment: And are you using C++11?

Comment: Yes, I included functional, but I only have Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: In that case, just get rid of the curly braces.